# C# Winforms panel autoscroll

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I have autoscroll Panel with PictureBox inside. On button click it changes PictureBox size (like zoom):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Height *= 2;
    pictureBox1.Width *= 2;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

After that, if panel was scrolled to 1/2, it becomes 1/4. I cant figure out how to save relative position of scroll.

Comment: do you want to enlarge the scroll of panel as the picturebox?

Comment: not clear on what your problem is, **what becomes 1/4**?

Comment: I'll try to explain what i want: http://screenshot.ru/upload/images/2013/12/14/EYzqtVfb.png